# Managed Solution not importing file that is included within the .zip

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013, solution

I'm using the XRM.Webform plugin for Dynamics 2013 published by powerxrm.com
Theres an error in that jquery 2.2.0 is not being included in the web resources upon import, however an inspection to the .zip file shows that jquery220min is included...
What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

powerxrm webform for dynamics 2013 appears to be out of date.
I was able to use powerobjects powerwebform to accomplish the same thing.
https://www.powerobjects.com/powerpacks/powerwebform/